# How do I add a special CSS class to run only on IE for a div component?

Tags: css, class, html, internet-explorer-9

I have a div component in html and it has a css class but this css not working good on IE 9 so I want to run another css class if the browser is IE 9 How?

Comment: That may not be the solution. Perhaps your current code can be re-worked to solve this problem. Without being able to see it, no one can really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [comperehensive article](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) on the subject. In brief,

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9.css">
<![endif]-->
```

should do the trick.

Here is the solution that worked for OP:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <link id="Link13" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" type="text/css" href="../English/Styles/WallSheetIE9.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: That what working with me 
<!--[if IE 9]>
 <link id="Link13" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" type="text/css" href="../English/Styles/WallSheetIE9.css">
    <!--<![endif]-->

Answer (score 1):

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-specific-for-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- [if IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="myIE9Style.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

can be used to import a style relative to IE 9

with that said, if statements in markup are...an eyesore, use them sparingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/ie9.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Add this to the `<head>` of your page under the title tag with the rest of the stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--[if IE9]>

<![endif]>
```

Usually does the trick, you can also do some variations - if say for another less than IE9 and so forth.

if it's a div component that you want it to run then you would need to

```
<!--[if IE 9 ]> <div class="anotherclass"> <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <link id="Link13" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" type="text/css" href="../English/Styles/WallSheetIE9.css">
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

That is what i tried and working good